# Copy file from directories with today's date to another location

Tags: powershell

AD Manager Plus generates reports hourly to a time stamped file path and I would like to copy these files to another location - overwriting the existing file. I will then schedule the script to run hourly after the files have been generated. Unfortunately the location the reports are extracted to cannot be modified and it creates date & time stamped folders.

**Example:**

```
C:\ADManager Plus\audit-data\reports\16042019\DailyTrue-Up01-55-07\Real Last Logon.xls
C:\ADManager Plus\audit-data\reports\ddmmyyyy\DailyTrue-Uphh-mm-ss\Real Last Logon.xls
```

I thought the easiest approach would be to:

- Get the last modified folder in the Reports Folder - eg `Apr162019`
- Get the last modified folder in the Apr162019 Folder - eg `DailyTrue-Up01-55-07`
- Filter for the Real Last Logon.xls spreadsheet in folder `DailyTrue-Up01-55-07`

```cs
$Path = "C:\ADManager Plus\audit-data\reports"
$DestinationPath = "\\domain\networkshare\Reports\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path\$_" -File -Filter "Real Last Logon.xlsx" |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1 |
        Copy-Item -Force -Destination (New-Item -Force -Type Directory -Path (Join-Path $DestinationPath ($_.FullName.Replace("$Path\", ''))))
}
```

The code we have seems to copy all folders to the location and can't look in multiple directories.

I got a feeling we are approaching this wrong, Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this? There are few posts online that explain how to **retrieve** files from time stamped folders.

Comment: I think on your second `Get-ChildItem` I think you need to add the `-Recurse` switch for it to go into the folder structure, as the file is one folder deeper.

Comment: Your `Get-ChildItem` with the `-File` parameter doesn't `-recurse` and shouldn't grep any xlsx file burrowed in subfolders.

Comment: Thanks, so now I have the following code that does locate the last modified file in the directory however not sure how to move this file: `code` $DestinationPath = "C:\ADManager Plus\audit-data\reports"
$path="\\domain\networkshare\Reports\"

$NoOfDirs=Get-ChildItem $path -Directory 
ForEach($dir in $NoOfDirs )
{

 Get-ChildItem  "$path\$($dir.name)" -File -Recurse | 
 Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt ([DateTime]::Now.Adddays(-1))} | 
 Select-Object @{l='Folder';e={$dir.Name}},Name,LastWriteTime | 
 Sort-Object  -pro LastWriteTime -Descending |
 Select -First 1
    
  
}